# How to keep folder when copying to output in MS Build?

Tags: .net-core, msbuild

Here's my code:

```
    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="$(ProjectDir)..\Translations\**\*.*">
         <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
```

Basically I tell the project to go on folder up, and copy **EVERYTHIN** inside `Translations` folder to the output directory.

However, when I go to the output, I see that there is not `Translations` directory. Only its files are copied directly inside the `bin` folder.

What I want is to preserve that `Translations` folder too. In other words, the files should be copied to `bin\Translations` directory.

What should I do to get that result?

Comment: have you tried to update the path to `$(ProjectDir)..\Translations` ? that will point to the folder instead

Comment: @FirdausKamaruddin, I encountered this error: `Error MSB3025 The source file "C:\Company\Product\Translations" is actually a directory.  The "Copy" task does not support copying directories.`